# Make div width vary with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

I have a `div` in which I generate content every half a second via the following function:

```
function ClockAndCalendar() {
  var da = new Date();
  var hours = da.getHours();
  var minutes = da.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  var actualTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
  var wd = weekday[da.getDay()];
  var month = mon[da.getMonth()];
  var curDate = da.getDate();
  var suffix = ending[da.getDate() - 1];
  var timeAndDate = (actualTime + " " + wd + ", " + month + " " + curDate + suffix + ", " + y);
  var newDiv = $('#date-and-time').text(timeAndDate);

  return newDiv;
}
var getTimeDateCalendar = setInterval(ClockAndCalendar, 500);
```

The `div` `#date-and-time` is nested in the following `div` like so:

```html
 <div id="calDateTimeBox">
      <i id="clock-link" class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" data-title="Click to show calendar."></i>
      <div id="date-and-time">10:06PM Wednesday, March 29th, 2017</div>
    </div>
```

with `#calDateTimeBox` and `#clock-link` having CSS:

```
#calDateTimeBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  margin-left: -357px; 
  width: 340px;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Many Secrets';
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

#clock-link {
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

When the times and dates are on the longer side, the div looks like so:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Is it possible, using jQuery, to get the `div` to adjust when the content overflows to a second line? If so, how would I achieve that effect?

Comment: why is the width fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
#calDateTimeBox {
   width: 340px;
}
```

to:

```
#calDateTimeBox {
   min-width: 340px;
}
```

And problem seems solved. This would still make the date go to the other line if the parent container isn't wide enough to accommodate it.

You can also add:

```
#date-and-time {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend that because your text will be cut off / show outside of the div container.